# How to display inline errors in the editor

Tags: phpstorm

On the scrollbar, the yellow areas designate *warnings* in the code. When hovering them, we get a nice preview of the code along with message labels at the end of the line, as seen in the screenshot below:

[image: PHPStorm inline error in preview]

I find this really nice and would like to display them all the time directly in the code editor. I looked up a bit and didn't find any option for that. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Not possible. But if you want to see a list of all errors for this file/folder/whole project -- use `Code | Inspect Code...`

Comment: Thank you, clear answer. I'll probably want to add this idea in their bug-tracker then. Could you post a "real" answer so I can tick it "Accepted"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it is not possible: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139324 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.

It works like that only in Code Lense mode which allows you to preview small chunk of another part of your file together with errors/warnings/etc.

But if you want to see a list of all errors for this file/folder/whole project -- use `Code | Inspect Code...`.

Comment: Thank you, bonus for the term "Code Lense" I can put a name on it now!